# HTTP 200 occurs 2 times around HTTP 304

Tags: django, jquery-mobile, http-status-code-304, http-status-code-200

Hi I am using Django and jQuery Mobile and I get 2 HTTP 200's surrounding a bunch of HTTP 304's per page refresh. I commented out all my javascript includes, but I still get this, so I don't think it's jQuery mobile that's the problem. It may be that I just don't understand 304's but I looked around at why there are 2 HTTP 200 requests surrounding the HTTP 304's but I couldn't find an answer, so I presume this is not natural.

[image]

Comment: A 304 just means not modified. It means the web browser said "give me this file. By the way I already have a copy from previously with this date." The the server replied "oh that's fine, it's not modified since then anyway, keep using that copy." 304 is not an error.

Comment: my question is why there are 1 HTTP 200's surrounding the 304's. I know what 304 means to that basic level

Comment: 200 is success. The browser passed a directory path so the server has no way to know if the file was seen before so it servers up the default file (index.html/php/whatever) and returns success (200). Are you asking why specifically the browser requests the index twice? I have no idea. Have you tried using firebug or a js debugger?

Answer (score 0):

A 304 code means content not modified. It's normal to see if a client has contacted the server previously.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser still caching the pages with the javascript/css includes, that is why even after the comment, it still request the files, but the server response was 304 means not modified.

Comment: my question is why there are 1 HTTP 200's surrounding the 304's. I know what 304 means to that basic level

Comment: You are making the request 2 times, check your code !